# Trusty Software Updater does not propose updates from trusty-updates

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates, update-manager

I have since one week upgraded several PC to Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty Tahr.

I got several updates via the Software Updater, but I don't get updates from trusty-updates, although this repository is selected in the settings dialog:

```
{here was a nice screenshot of the dialog showing:
X Important security updates (trusty-security)
X Recommended updates (trusty-updates)
O Pre-released updates (trusty-proposed)
X Unsupported updates (trusty-backports)

Automatically check for updates: Daily
Where there are security updates: Display immediately
Where there are other udpates: Display weekly
Notify me of a new Ubuntu version: For long-term support versions
}
```

There are however several updates available:

```
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  compiz compiz-core compiz-gnome compiz-plugins compiz-plugins-default compiz-plugins-main-default
  compizconfig-backend-gconf compizconfig-settings-manager gir1.2-nautilus-3.0 gir1.2-rb-3.0 libcompizconfig0
  libdecoration0 libgexiv2-2 libido3-0.1-0 libnautilus-extension1a librhythmbox-core8 libselinux1
  libselinux1:i386 libselinux1-dev nautilus nautilus-data python-compizconfig python3-update-manager rhythmbox
  rhythmbox-data rhythmbox-mozilla rhythmbox-plugin-cdrecorder rhythmbox-plugin-magnatune
  rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist rhythmbox-plugins update-manager update-manager-core
32 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

I did not test them all, but all of which I tested come from trusty-updates:

```
$ apt-cache policy compiz nautilus update-manager
compiz:
  Installed: 1:0.9.11+14.04.20140409-0ubuntu1
  Candidate: 1:0.9.11+14.04.20140423-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
     1:0.9.11+14.04.20140423-0ubuntu1 0
        500 http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
 *** 1:0.9.11+14.04.20140409-0ubuntu1 0
        500 http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
nautilus:
  Installed: 1:3.10.1-0ubuntu8
  Candidate: 1:3.10.1-0ubuntu9
  Version table:
     1:3.10.1-0ubuntu9 0
        500 http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
 *** 1:3.10.1-0ubuntu8 0
        500 http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
update-manager:
  Installed: 1:0.196.11
  Candidate: 1:0.196.12
  Version table:
     1:0.196.12 0
        500 http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
 *** 1:0.196.11 0
        500 http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Updates from trusty-security are done however. So I don't know if that's a bug or something I misconfigured?

[UPDATE]:

- To answer comment below, I have some warnings / errors in `~/.cache/software-center/` as of today. Warnings like `'WARNING:main:no data`, and even one `ERROR - trying to repair DB failed`. But they don't reproduce afterwards.
- Also, one of the package is `compiz`. I went to check the changelog on Launchpad, and noticed the following history page: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/amd64/compiz. It says "Phased updates", "40% of users". Could this be linked to that? Is there a way to bypass this phased updates when using the *Software Updater* (as when using `apt-get`)?

Comment: Looks like it could be a bug in software-center. Do you see any errors in _~/.cache/software-center/software-center.log_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hm, this seems to be exactly what PhasedUpdates are. Also check out http://www.murraytwins.com/blog/?p=127 and http://lwn.net/Articles/563966/.

To summarize links above:

- Ubuntu quietly introduced a new mechanism in its 13.04 release that progressively rolls out package updates, pushing each update to a small subset of the total user base first, then steadily scaling up, rather than publishing the update for everyone simultaneously.
- On the client end, phased updates are implemented in the `update-manager` tool, which is Ubuntu's graphical update installation application. The other methods for updating a package, such as `apt-get`, are not affected by the phased update plan.
- `update-manager` generates a random number between zero and one for each package, then compares it to the `Phased-Update-Percentage` value published on the server for that package. If `update-manager`'s generated number is less than the published percentage, then the package will be added to the list of available updates that the user can install. Dependencies for a package are pulled in automatically.
- One can opt out of the Phased Update process by adding the following to the configuration file `/etc/apt/apt.conf`:

  ```
  Update-Manager::Never-Include-Phased-Updates “True”;
  ```

Here a one-liner to print all packages with the `Phased-Update-Percentage` tag:

```
apt-cache show ".*"|sed -r '/^Package:/h;/^Phased-Update-Percentage:/{H;x;s/\n/\n\t/;p};d'
```

Comment: Links can change at any time so may not be useful in the future.  Please summarize the answer as well as providing links.

Answer (score 1):

You have selected to display updates from trusty-updates weekly. I suggest you to change this setting to "Display immediately" and Security updates to "Download and install automatically".

[image]

Also, it will be convenient to use unattended-upgrades. Run

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure unattended-upgrades
```

and select "Yes".

Comment: I just tried that, but no difference. *Software-update* still says everything is up-to-date, while apt-get proposed new updates. But see my update in my post re. phased updates. Is that the cause?

Comment: Seems not. If it was, there probably would be no updates in `apt-get upgrade`. May be bain knows better. I have never seen this problem before.

Comment: @fuujuhi: It actually could be that. My guess is that `apt-get` and `apt` just download the files and think "Oh, there are new packages available. Let's get them.". However, the Software Updater also checks the phased update attribute (was that introduced recently?) and, in this case, doesn't distribute it since it is for 0% of users (i.e. those updating through the command line or Synaptic can get it, but not standard users) (to limit the regression potential).